# How to download thousands of files quickly?

Tags: wget, download

I need to download thousands of files (approximately 2-12 MB each) - Currently I am using the following command

```
wget --reject "index.html*" -A *.gz -N -r -l1  -nd --no-check-certificate --user USERNAME --password PASSWORD -np http://website.org/subfolder/
```

Each connection seems to be limited at 100Kb/s though. How could I go about downloading these much faster? If possible 50+ active connections (1 per file)

Comment: Is the 100kb/sec limit on your side or of the website? Perhaps you could start several `wget` processes in the background with something like ` for first_letter in {a..z}; do echo wget $first_letter\*.gz \&; done` (without the `echo`). Depending on the filenames you could arrange the `{a..z}` to also include upper case letters, `{A..Z}`, or numerals: `{0..9}`.